Portugal tourist or visitor visa
I have been living in Portugal for the last 5 years. I have 3 years of residency. Can I sponsor my brother, who is living in India, in the means of a responsibility letter or cover letter, to come here to meet me? Would it help him get a visa?

Does this answer your question? Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing? His chances depend on his personal circumstances, for example if he has a good travel history/job/ties to India his chances will be better than if he is unemployed, single, no savings.
